# Web scraping R - can I extract the data or just the picture from this page?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am looking at this ULR:
https://finanzen.handelsblatt.com/22394404/lng-japan-korea-marker-platts
Can anyone tell me if I can extract the data of the graph or only the figure which contains the data?

I am really not familiar with this structure and didnt get further when I inspected the page.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to close as OP is asking for tool or tutorial. Also, given graph is a png image and data extraction from an image is different from a web-scraping.

Comment: I am not asking for a tutorial at all. I would be very grateful if someone pointed me in the right direction! Thats all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little research around 'rvest'. Here's a snippet;

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://finanzen.handelsblatt.com/22394404/lng-japan-korea-marker-platts'
pg <- read_html(url)

pg %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
pg %>% html_nodes('.vhb-full-width .vhb-after') %>% html_text()

## > pg %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text()
##[1] "LNG Japan/Korea Marker (Platts" 
##> pg %>% html_nodes('.vhb-full-width .vhb-after') %>% html_text()
##[1] "9,81"
```